# Installing Ruby version 2.2.4 on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I had an old version of Ruby (1.9.3) that I am using with Selenium Webdriver.But I was getting errors while running my script.So I downloaded Ruby installer 2.2.4 version and ran it. Can someone tell me what is the command line steps to fully install it ? I tried "gem update --system" and I get the error "error fetching data". I tried "gem install ruby" and it says "successfully installed rubyzip 1.1.7"

Comment: If you're going to update, which is not a bad idea, why not go to the latest version? 2.3.0 came out in December.

Comment: Did you look at the install instructions?

Comment: @tadman All I want is a new version of selenium.I am facing the same issue in case of any version i install.Do you have the steps to complete this action ?

Comment: @JeffC I do not see any other instructions apart from the command line steps I entered.I would appreciate if you can share the step by step process. May be I am missing something since I am not a pro

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ruby on Windows is best done by downloading the installer from [the Ruby Installer site](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) and executing the binary. There are a few things to look out for:

Make sure the correct Ruby is in your PATH. E.g.:

```
echo %PATH%
```

should include a string like `C:\Ruby200\bin`. The installation path may be different for your version of Ruby. If you are installing a new version, you might need to edit the path using the Windows dialog so that new sessions include it.

Also, read the instructions for installing the [Ruby DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit). You'll need it for installation of gems with native extensions.

Once Ruby is installed correctly you should be able to run `ruby -v` in a command window to see that the expected version is there.
\